Looking for a film about a mob boss trying to recover money and kills the parents in a family
English movie, origin USA, year? probably in the late 90's.

Mob boss wants his money back
Sent his men to kill the people who took it in a dormant account
Family moves in a new house in a quite place.
Bad guys shows up looking for the money killing the mother and later the father inside the hauling truck.  
Boy (mentally disturbed, high IQ) and step sister (her hand was injured) fought back killing the bad guys one by one in the forest, car park and inside their house by setting up traps.     
Money is hidden in a mattress
Final bad guy was killed in the basement, (blinded by fumes, stepping on nails and finally crushed by a cabinet) 
Ending, the boss received photos of the people killed by his men including dead photos of his men as well. The boy and his sister rammed the trailer office of the boss.   


Welcome to Movies & TV! I've edited your question title to make it more useful. If you feel I have misunderstood you, please feel free to [edit] it yourself. In future, please make sure your title is descriptive and that it accurately represents your question.

Ah, my first answer here. :)

@Walt Are you sure this asks the exact same question as the supposed duplicate? This question seem way more detailed than the other one.
